# Generating and storing unique ID using uuid in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, uuid

I am trying to generate a unique user ID using python's `uuid` and then store it in my mysql database.
I am confused as to when I should generate the ID.

This is my `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
import uuid

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = models.EmailField(required=True)
    user_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    class meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
        )

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    user.user_id = uuid.uuid4()

    if commit:
        user.save()

    return user
```

This is the registration portion of my views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save
            return redirect('/account')

        else:
            form = RegistrationForm()

            args = {'form':form}
            return render(request, 'accounts/registration.html', args)
```

Comment: There's quite a lot wrong with this question, but the main thing is that you seem to be confusing forms and models. You can't use model fields in a form.

Comment: I was watching a tutorial and that's the way the uploader did it. I just followed his lead. Why can't I use model fields in a form?

Comment: Because forms and models aren't the same thing. This code doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: In general you do not need to specify a user ID manually as Django will create one for you. I suggest reading the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/) then coming back and editing your question to make it more specific

Answer (score 0):

First, what you are trying to do is [Extending core User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model). You must choose one of two ways to do it. I would recommend creating one-to-one model with all necessary additional fields, such as your uuid ID.

Second, the code

```
user_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

is for describing a field in **models.py** (not in forms). If you put it here you don't have to think about generating id, you have already set a callable uuid4 for it. Read more at [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield).